# Connect to a server not on port 25565

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to run 2 Minecraft servers on my VPS, normal and a Bukkit server for playing with mods. I believe I have the both running (Normal on 25565 and Bukkit on 25566), however, when I try and connect (using `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:25566`) it doesn't connect.

Is that all I need to do to connect using a different port (IE the issue is with my server) or do I need to connect a different way (IE My servers okay I'm just trying to connect wrong)?

Comment: Did you forward the Bukkit server to port 25566?

Comment: In server.properties I set it to `25566`, do I need to do anything else?

Comment: does your firewall allow connections to port 25566?

Comment: I believe that might be my issue, I've added it to `iptables` but I can't check until I get home in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

turn on the servers and then use [this tool](http://www.canyouseeme.org/) to check if the ports are open and accepting connections, if not then you need to go to your router's settings page (dependant on router, so just google "'your router brand' settings page" to see how to get there and open up ports correctly).